# Best practice: access DAO without making it Singleton

Tags: java, singleton, dao

I have a JavaFX GUI with a main controller class (basically just a wrapper, not doing much till now) and two injected/included controllers for parts of the GUI. This is to keep things separate and not overload the controller class. Both controllers are connected using a mediator class, because buttons in one of the controllers affect GUI elements in the other one.

My problem is as follows: user interaction will cause both graphical changes as well as changes to the database. Therefore, I will likely have to access the DAO I've created at various points inside my controller classes - two at the moment, but maybe several more as the application grows. 
I've read that using the Singleton pattern for DAOs is common, but actually not very good practice. Consequently, I'm looking for alternatives: how could I pass commands to my DAO from different points of my program, especially if I don't have direct control over the creation of controller classes (as they are loaded via FXML loader on the `<fx:include>` commands)? Passing around an instance seems difficult here.

Many thanks in advance!

PS: I deliberately did not post any code here, because most of the existing stuff is imho not relevant for  the question and the other code is not written yet (as it's currently being planned :-P ). If you need it, just let me know.

Comment: If I were you, I would only modify the database using those button calls. I would instead have the application set up, so that it is listening to the database and its UI reflects the state of the DB. This way, your UI never accidentally reflects the wrong state. If something fails, your UI will still reflect the correct state.

Comment: Most databases have APIs for listening for changes. (Instead of constantly polling the database).

Comment: One alternative to the Singleton pattern is to Just Use One.

Comment: @Dylan: interesting point... but wouldn't modifying the DB inside the button's event handlers somewhat mess up the MVC approach (i.e. separating data logic from graphics)?

Comment: Well yes, but you can still use DAO to do this. I just meant to call your DAO stack from the button. And instead of modifying the UI right away from that same method. Allow your design pattern listen for changes and do it for you. You can still sepearate the logic using DAO.

Comment: OK, I see. But to use the DAO from inside the event handler, the controller class (or whatever contains the handler) still has to have some knowledge about the DAO class - which is where the problems come in. Or did I miss your point?